# Is it possible to run a SQL Stored Procedure from an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I need to create an HTML based file for end-users to input search criteria into, such as an account number, this will then pass that parameter into the SQL Stored Procedure.
In my Stored Procedure I have a parameter of "@accountNumber".

I only need a simple for with 1 input to display the queries results.

I have tried several different methods, however none have worked, these methods included me googling and altering code.. however I could not find anything that was enough to what I am trying to do specifically that I could get to work.

Comment: Sure you can, just have the form submit to a URL which runs a server-side script which invokes the stored procedure. (Or you could use Ajax if you want to process the response without having the whole page reload.)

Comment: You run a stored procedure the same way you run any other query.

Comment: This is pretty standard web application functionality - user inputs a value, and submits a form. Request is sent to server. Server side code reads the form data from the request, and passes it to database query as a parameter. Query runs, server code gets result, formats it and returns it to the browser. The database query can be a stored procedure, no problem. people do it all the time. So... you'll have to be more specific about your issue. What exactly goes wrong in your code when you try this? Can we see the code? It's very hard to fix things we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

James.

I'm sure you have a server-side engine (PHP,Node.js,etc...) that handles the web service.
Your HTML/Javascript site is only the frontend.

You should call the Stored Procedure from the server side.
I'm assuming the SQL Engine runs also on your server.

**Also, and very important**:
You should check that the SQL user that your site uses to execute the query has the privileges to run that (or any) Stored Procedure.
Otherwise, you'll get no answer from the SQL server.

Hope it helps